# Drawing a bufferedimage slow in Windows, fast in Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swing

Alright, for a class project a I and a few others are working on an isometric game. Everything is being drawn in one JPanel using a buffered image. Anyways, each piece of artwork is specifically done in fireworks and saved as a .png. On Linux, the time it takes to redraw the map every game tick is around 3ms. On Windows (and also OSx) it's around 100ms spiking to 500ms. This effect has been observed on 4 different computers ranging from typical laptop to an i7-3770K + 660 gaming machine. The CPU usage when this occurs is around 10-20% with RAM usage of the program being around 1GB. The problem has been researched on the internet in many places to no avail and also our section leaders (who are in charge of the project) were stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: "feature X slow in Windows, fast in Linux" - why am I not surprised?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: Linux has a better timer resolution that Windows does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the paint component in the JPanel and the setEntityImage method. You can see where the time stamps are pulled from at the bottom of the paintComponent. The setEntityImage is being set every 500ms with a new BufferedImage that is pre-drawn on another thread before being passed into this JPanel. I'm including that code as I'm also curious if it's a possible threading issue.

```
public void setEntityImage(BufferedImage entityImg)
{
    this.entityImg = entityImg;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.fillRect(0, 0, tileImg.getWidth(), tileImg.getHeight());

    // Draw tiles
    g2.drawImage(tileImg, 0, 0, null);

    // Draw box over square mouse is hovering over
    if (hover)
    {
        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 128));
        int screenX = (this.x * 16 - this.y * 16) + Window.WIDTH * 16;
        int screenY = (this.x * 8 + this.y * 8) + 16;

        g2.drawLine(screenX, screenY + 8, screenX + 16, screenY);
        g2.drawLine(screenX + 16, screenY, screenX + 32, screenY + 8);
        g2.drawLine(screenX, screenY + 8, screenX + 16, screenY + 16);
        g2.drawLine(screenX + 16, screenY + 16, screenX + 32, screenY + 8);
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    g2.drawImage(entityImg, 0, 0, null);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
}
```